# How do I invoke the exec-maven-plugin's java goal with the mainClass parameter from the command line?

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

The Exec Maven Plugin Documentation states for the java goal that I can provide the main class parameter like this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.my.MainClass"
```

However when I invoke the goal this way I always get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project APIEndpoint: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

The class is compiled and resides in `target > classes > com > my`. What am I missing here? Do I need to add the plugin to my `pom.xml` but without the configuration tags? Am I correct to assume that maven and the exec goal do all the classpath resolving automatically?

Comment: Strange. Getting this error as well. Should work though :(

Comment: Are you trying to run the "main" class from a spring boot project? This might be the problem. spring-boot creates the jar in a different way (different inner folder) and runs the user's code from a different class loader. A different ball game.